# prompt() function returns undefined in UIWebView IOS Simulator

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, undefined, prompt

```
var x=prompt('Test Me','Default');
alert(x);
```

Run this from Safari - everything is fine.

Run this from a wrapped UIWebView and `x` comes back undefined no matter what the input (after pressing OK).

Is this a bug - is there workaround?

Note: tested on 6.0.1 Device and Xcode simulator (Version 6.0 358.4).

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried it out and it seems to be working just fine. Try renaming your variable in case you used the variable name anywhere else. Also if you can, try running it in a web browser and see if it brings up the error. Cheers :D